# Last efforts (I hope) for configuring an Apache2 SSL reverse proxy

Tags: apache, ssl, proxy

I'm rather tired, anyway I resolved seveal previous errors. The architecture is still the same:

```
               http               https
middleware -----------> proxy -------------> backend
```

I limited the confguration to one single file: /etc/apache2/conf.d/sites-available/sole.conf

this is the content (proxy in a Ubuntu 18.04 machine)

```
# sole.conf
LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPreserveHost off
    SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile /usr/local/etc/apache2/ssl.crt/client.pem

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass        /sole https://remoteserver.com/somepath
    ProxyPassReverse /sole https://remoteserver.com/somepath

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_sole.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_sole.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The result, calling http://localhost/sole with SoapUI, is this:

```
!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>502 Proxy Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Proxy Error</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.<br />
The proxy server could not handle the request<p>Reason: <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong></p></p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

I was afraid the backend not to receive the client certificate, but now that message disappeared and looking at the Wireshark logs, Chiper exchange is taking place:

[Wireshark screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie3Hh.png)

So I don't know what else to think about. Is there still anybody wrong in my solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: share your error and access log snippet.

Comment: [Thu Jun 18 19:06:00.526490 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 16787] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client 127.0.0.1:60314] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server remoteserver.com:443

[Thu Jun 18 19:06:00.526685 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 16787] [client 127.0.0.1:60314] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /sole

Comment: set `force-proxy-request-1.0 1 SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1` in virtualHost and test

Comment: Also you can set `LogLevel debug dumpio:trace7 ssl:trace8 proxy_http:trace8` in Apache httpd  for more debugging log.

Comment: Oh thanks! Plenty of details... Now I try to see

Comment: share latest log.

Comment: Please read what the [tag:apache] tag has to say about Apache configuration questions

Comment: I cannot read anymore the last comments we exchanged